# Yodlee service returns empty result in windows server

Tags: windows, yodlee

I have downloaded the REST C# sample code from yodlee. Then it has been compiled in visual studio and uploaded under virtual directory in windows server. Now the problem is,

While calling the cobrand service (SampleApps/SampleAppService.svc/rest/login/cobrand) to get CToken, it returns empty value as,

```
Body: ""
isValid: true
```

But it works fine in local system.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you receiving any fault message as well? Is your server's IP is white listed at Yodlee?

Comment: There is no fault messages and IP address is not white listed... @pushpraj Ruhal

Comment: Then perhaps you may need to create a SR at Yodlee to white list your server IP, it may take a week as Yodlee does it on Wednesdays or Thursdays only. Before that you can make sure that you are using correct set of credentials ie. cobrand id, app id, login and password

Comment: But it works fine, returns data in local system(runs from visual studio) and for php code also it works fine in php live server.. Problem is only in windows server..

Comment: Can you please check if your windows server's firewall is blocking the request? And could you also please test if you are able to access(or get response) any other API(not related to Yodlee)?

Comment: @Apoorv - Sorry for the late reply.. There is something weird in hostgator shared server.. but finally it works fine in azure.. Thankyou

Comment: @Kannanyii - Great finally it worked for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if your windows server's firewall is blocking the request? And could you also please test if you are able to access(or get response) any other API(not related to Yodlee)?

Comment: As for yodlee developer account its works fine in azure server. But now i have tried to login with yodlee real account cobrand username, password and REST url to fetch cobrand session token. It returns the exception of invalid cobrand credentials when i have tried from live server and it returns response of (Body: "" isValid: true) when i have tried from local environment. But my credentials are correct..  @Apoorv